# What is the use of "_version" within collections?

Tags: c#, collections, enumerator

I was curious about collections and was looking at the source code for many of the popular ones (List, Dictionary, etc). I've noticed that a lot of them (all of them?) use an integer called "_version" (or a variance thereof) within their code, which is added to everytime a change happens to the collection. It appears to be used in their IEnumerator implementations, checking if the Enumerator version is the same as the collection's.

The two questions I have:

1. Why do Enumerators have need to check for "versions"? What would cause an Enumerator's version to be different from the collection's?
2. Should people making custom enumerable collections bother implementing their own "_version" in their code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would cause an Enumerator's version to be different from the collection's?

If you change the collection after the Enumerator is created.  In other words, _version is there to check if the collection is changed while you're iterating through it.

> Should people making custom enumerable collections bother implementing their own "_version" in their code?

Depends on how "safe" you want your collection to be.  Do you want to throw an exception if the user does something they shouldn't, or just wander off into undefined-behavior land?

Comment: Re-reading that my last sentence might come off as sarcastic, but I should expound that it isn't.  Allowing for undefined behavior by getting rid of the bookkeeping associated with _version will make your collection more performant.  Which is why C++ has undefined behavior lurking all around, whereas .NET generally prefers the safety-first approach.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't take it as sarcastic. Thank you! @IceGlasses

Answer (score 2):

"_version" is used to keep enumerator in sync with collection.

There is good explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11297012/2178028

> Reference:
>
> What changes the "version" of a list and thus invalidates all current
> enumerators?
>
> Changing an element through the indexer
>
> - Add
> - AddRange
> - Clear
> - Insert
> - InsertRange
> - RemoveAll
> - RemoveAt
> - RemoveRange
> - Reverse
> - Sort